# Web Cache Deception vulnerability (flagged by NetSparker)

Tags: web-services, security, websecurity

Our application was flagged by Netsparker as having a **Web Cache Deception** vulnerability.

> the attacker uses the acquired link, for example
> https://example.com/settings.php and appends a path with a file
> extension, which may look like a static stylesheet or image.
>
> The attacker would then send the manipulated link to the victim. Once
> the victim's browser accesses the URL, it sends along the victim's
> cookies. So the cache server would receive the request for example for
> https://example.com/settings.php/stylesheet.css and will treat it as a
> static stylesheet file. In many environments where aggressive caching
> is needed to keep the number of requests to the server as low as
> possible, the cache server may override the Cache-Control header sent
> by the application and use the public cache control directive for all
> files ending in .css. This means that the page will be cached for all
> users of the site, even though its content belongs to a single user
> and may contain sensitive data.

In our case, the scan tried

```
https://app.com/myapp//ns.css
```

and got some kind of result,

```
Response Time (ms) : 18.8747 Total Bytes Received : 3754 Body Length : 3321 Is Compressed : No
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.4.48 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1k
Expires: Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 3321
Last-Modified: Tue, 31 Aug 2021 17:02:00 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 31 Aug 2021 19:32:23 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/><meta http-equiv="Pragma" cont
ent="no-cache"/><meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="ico
n" href="/ets/favicon.ico"/>
```

But what should have been the result? A 404 error? We have a React application and the result was a blank page due to a mismatched route.

Comment: Hi, did you figure this out?

Comment: No. We just created a "Page Not Found" page for anything not matching our officially supported Router URLs (we have a React app), and URLs with this .css are captured by "Page Not Found". Then we ignored this item from the report.